# in mvc the view is not receiving a list while the controller class is sending it correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending a list from controller to view but the view is not receiving it despite the list being populated in the controller

Controller:

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Department
    public ActionResult Index() {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
        List<Department> departments = 
        employeeContext.Departments.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model  IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Department>
@using MVCDemo.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Departments List";
}
<div style="font-family:Arial">
<h2>Departments List</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (Department Department in  @model) {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(Department.name, "Index","Employee", new { 
        departmentid = Department.ID })</li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not passing the list to the view, do this: `return View(departments);`

Comment: yeah it worked. Thankyou so much for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller{
// GET: Department
public ActionResult Index() {
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
    List<Department> departments = 
    employeeContext.Departments.ToList();
    return View(departments);
}}
```